# Add class based on current page

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am new to this and it is so confusing for me so I will ask a stupid question.

I am having simple layout like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - TDMajstor</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/_Layout.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <div id="MainWrapper">
        <div id="HorizontalMenuWrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="Pocetna" href="@Url.Page("./Index")">Pocetna</a></li>
                <li><a id="Google" href="https://google.com">Google</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is to add class `active` to ONE of my links.

So how can I make an expression and add class to link when page load based on the current page link.

So code should be something like this:

```
if(CurrentlyOpenedLink == "someLink")
{
    Pocetna.AddClass("active");
}
else if(CurrentlyOpenedLink == "someLink")
{
    Google.AddClass("active");
}
```

- Where to write code like this (it is just templated I do not know exact code)
- How to write it (so what functions to use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to create your own razor extension.

`@` in razor means an object that type is `HtmlHelper<T>`

Here is a simple code you can follow

```
public static class HelpExt
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomerLink<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        string url, 
        object htmlAttributes)
    {
        TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("a");
        builder.MergeAttribute("src", url);
        builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

This link have more detail about [Build HTML Helpers](https://forums.asp.net/t/1923953.aspx?Custom+MVC+Extension+Methods)

**EDIT**

In you question you there is a simple way can make your expect, add class tag in tag and add some judge.

use `@{}` contain your c# colde to judge your `CurrentlyOpenedLink`  value.

if you want to get  currently opened link you can use `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`.

```
<li><a id="Pocetna" href="@Url.Page("./Index")" class='@{CurrentlyOpenedLink == "somelink1" ? "active" : ""}'>Pocetna</a></li>
<li><a id="Google" href="https://google.com" class='@{CurrentlyOpenedLink == "somelink" ? "active" : ""}'>Google</a></li>
```

if you want to set value in `CurrentlyOpenedLink` string you can add this in razor top.

```
@{
    string CurrentlyOpenedLink = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

Comment: Maybe i am wrong but in that link it is referring to MVC (.aspx) but i am having razor (.cshtml). Anyway where should i put that code? Plus additional problem is that my code is from `layout` not `page` so i do not have `model` (if it means something)

Comment: I got to that part but i do not know how to get `CurrentlyOpenedLink`

Comment: I have been trying that but `The name Request does not exist in current context` - I am using `ASP .Net Core 2.0`

Comment: Try to use `Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`

Comment: It doesn't exist. I managed to do it with `string currLink = Context.Request.Host.ToString() + Context.Request.Path;` but is there simpler way?

Comment: You can add `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions` namespace then `@Context.Request.GetDisplayUrl()`

Comment: P.S. your "if-else" statement didn't work but i made it work like this: `<li><a href="@Url.Page("./Index")" class="@(currLink == Url.Page("./Index") ? "Active" : "")">Pocetna</a></li>`

Answer (score 0):

As I understood,
You want to be a navigation link to be highlighted when you goes to respective page

So for you can do this by using Jquery.

```
if (CurrentlyOpenedLink == "Pocetna") {
    $(document.querySelector('#Pocetna')).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
  }
  else if (CurrentlyOpenedLink == "Google") {
    $(document.querySelector('#Google')).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
  }
```

**Edited:**

If you have to do it by MVC way then

1) Your Layout.cshtml look like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - TDMajstor</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/_Layout.css" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MainWrapper">
        <div id="HorizontalMenuWrapper">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="@ViewBag.Pocetna">@Html.ActionLink("Pocetna", "Pocetna", "Home")</li>
                            <li class="@ViewBag.Sample">@Html.ActionLink("Sample", "Sample", "Home")</li>
                            <li class="@ViewBag.Google"><a id="Google" href="https://google.com">Google</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
</body>
</html>
```

2) your Pocetna.cshtml look like

```
@{

    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Pocetna = "active";
}

<h2>Pocetna</h2>
```

3) Here I added one more page for you for better undrstanding e.g. sample.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sample";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Sample = "active";
}

<h2>Sample</h2>
```

Here I used **ViewBag** to indicate navbar that which page is currently active and depending upon we just apply class to respective **li** .

Try once may it helps you.

Comment: It may but one more problem i have here - `CurrentlyOpenedLink` is just word i made up so you know in that place i want to get currently opened link so how could i get it?

Comment: @Aleksa Ristic, be patience I'll try to create example for you

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Aleksa Ristic, Please view edited section in answer, If it helps then accept answer. I made some changes in your html you may ignore those